# Another error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++

I know this has been asked a thousand times but I can't fix this simple problem.

This is the code:

```
#include "windows.h"

extern "C"
{
    INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR strCmdLine, INT)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The subsystem is set to `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`. I have the following error:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup`

Comment: How is your project set up?  Are you sure your source file is getting compiled and linked?

Comment: The file is part of the project, and I have more files that are compiled as they give warnings. Also no, it isn't excluded

Comment: It smells fishy to me that you're compiling without `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` defined. The entry point should look like this: `int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);` [More on entry points on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406.aspx)

Comment: I am using `Use Multi-Byte Character Set` as it was asked by the framework I am using (Ogre)

Comment: That's...weird. It's the year 2013, you're really using a library that doesn't support Unicode? You might be wasting your time.

Comment: I am making a 3D game and Ogre looked really decent. Probably it has Unicode support and the tutorials are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused because the file were `WinMain` was defined was a `.h` file, and therefore it wasn't included in the project.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your `WinMain` function is declared in an `extern "C"` block, which gives it C-style linkage. The Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime expects there to be a function with the symbol `_WinMain@16`, which is the C++ symbol name for a `__stdcall` function that takes 16 bytes worth of arguments.

To solve this problem, remove the `extern "C"` linkage-specification block from around your `WinMain` function.